# Updating a dict in javascript with standard mathematical functions

Tags: javascript

This is a python code to create a dictionary and update it with standard mathematical functions. How can I do the same in javascript?

```
import math
Env = dict          # An environment is a mapping of {variable: value}
env = Env()
env.update(vars(math)) # sin, cos, sqrt, pi, ..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read properties of [`Math`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math) with [`getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) object and then [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) it:

```
const dict = {};
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Math).reduce((r, k) => {
  r[k] = Math[k];
  return r;
}, dict);
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a Dictionary use `JavaScript Objects`

`var dict = new Object(); // {};`

Usage:

`dict[yourKey] = yourValue;` // looks like {yourKey: yourValue} similar to python dicts

To use Mathematical functions use JavaScript `Math` Object

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math) you have complete documentaion of `Math`

example:

`Math.sin(0);           // 0`